# Onesignal web-push overwriting

Tags: php, push-notification, push, onesignal

I am using OneSignal web push notifications to deliver notifications to my clients from website built with PHP. After a while, I realized that if I send the first notification **but client do not open it on his device** and then I deliver another one, smartphones **will not stack them below each other** in the notification area but rather overwrite the first with the second one. This means that the client just missed first notification.

I, of course, tried to research on it before I asked here, but with no success - did I maybe overlook some section of the documentation explaining how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the official support for OneSignal and got a super simple but detailed solution - might you be dealing with similar issue, see copy of the e-mail below (thank you, Jon:)).

When using our REST API to programmatically send notifications, you can use the undocumented parameter **web_push_topic**.

In a set of notifications sharing the same web_push_topic, newly received notifications will replace older received notifications with the same topic. Only notifications sharing the same topic will be replaced; notifications without a topic or with a different topic will not be replaced. You can set different topics for different sets of notifications to control which notifications stay on screen.

The **web_push_topic** value can be any string value.

On Chrome, a maximum of 3 notifications is displayed at any time, even if the other notifications are not related to your site or from OneSignal. This means you can only show 3 categories of notifications to your user, not counting for other notifications that might be displayed at that time.

On Firefox on Windows, many more notifications can be shown at a time (6+).

On Firefox on Mac, and Safari on Mac, only one notification can be shown at a time, even if the other notifications are not related to your site or from OneSignal. Notifications also disappear quickly within 5 seconds and this time is not customizable.

On Chrome/Firefox on Android, multiple notifications can be shown at a time.

If you do not specify web_push_topic , each notification will be replaced by a newer notification. If you do specify web_push_topic, you can choose which notifications will be replaced and which notifications will stack.

When sending a notification using our API, setting a string value for web_push_topic will set the topic for the notification. Any notifications sharing the same topic will replace each other, but any notifications with a different topic won't be replaced.

So suppose you send 4 notifications:

Notification "Open house at 1234 Street at 3 PM this Saturday" with topic 'open-houses'.
Notification "Open house at 1234 Street changed to 4 PM this Saturday" with topic 'open-houses'.
Notification "20 new houses match your criteria in the Seattle, WA" with topic 'general-updates'.
Notification "Find an agent in your area" with topic 'promotional'.
The sequence of notifications observed will be:

Notification #1 shows.
Notification #2 replaces #1 (even if docked in Mac OS X's notification tray).
Notification #3 is shown separately (and if docked in Mac OS X's notification tray, it will use a separate entry).
Notification #4 is also shown separately.
In the end, when the subscriber checks his unread notifications, he will see three total notifications.

Hopefully that makes more sense!